# Is it possible to read vinyl records with a camera?

Tags: acoustics, image-processing

As far as I know a vinyl record stores information as surface irregularities in a spiral on a plastic disk. In theory is it possible to read this information based on a single or multiple photos of the disk?

Comment: Have you read this?  [Press Scan to Play Old Albums](https://www.wired.com/2003/02/press-scan-to-play-old-albums/)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Great article thanks! That answers my question.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Hmm what if we would make a negative copy of the disk? It might be much easier to measure how deep a valley is this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about physics

Comment: Humans can do this, too. Seems possible with sufficient familiarity with the piece of music to  have a part of the record highlighted and have a human read those grooves and hum out the piece. https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/the-record-reader/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, versions of optical turntables do exist. Check this [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_turntable) and the [ELP product](http://elpj.com) as examples. The main advantage of the optical LP players is that they can focus on an unworn area of the groove. This is important for restoring and digitizing vintage records. The main disadvantage is a hypersensitivity to any dust. While a mechanical stylus pushes small dust particles away, a laser beam reads them all as a signal. Also, the linearity and dynamic range of analog laser beam readers are not necessarily better than in mechanical cartridges. Finally, the groove angles are not optimized for optical reading.

To answer your specific question, it is possible to read lower frequencies off the photo with proper image processing. The groove modulation reflects an integral of the signal, because mechanical cartridges are sensitive to the speed, not displacement. In addition, a substantial and very specific frequency equalization is involved. However, reading higher frequencies off a photograph would be more difficult, because modulated groove sides are at 45 degrees to the surface and the depth of their modulation may not be immediately apparent on the photo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant something without a laser beam and any kind of rotation. So just a CCD camera in a fixed position and multiple light sources around the disk which you can turn on and off. Is it possible to extract the information from the disk using this kind of photos? If so how high resolution would it be necessary to do so?

Comment: @inf3rno, have you read this?  [Press Scan to Play Old Albums](https://www.wired.com/2003/02/press-scan-to-play-old-albums/)

Comment: @inf3rno Per RIAA, the Minimum Inside Diameter of Recording is 4 3/4". At 33 1/3 rpm and the upper audio range of 20kHz, you get a wavelength on the groove of 10.5um. Per Nyqvist, you need at least 2 pixels to resolve it. The Diameter of Outermost Groove at Recording Pitch is 11 1/2". Assuming a square censor, this gives the resolution of 55,500x55,500 pixels or 3,079 megapixels. So a 3 gigapixel censor or a 12"x12" scanner with a 200 lines per mm resolution. As I mentioned in the answer, reading higher frequencies may be a challenge.